# Как выполнять печать без переопределения настроек?

Tags: c#, pdf, принтер

Ситуация такая. Использую ghostscript для растеризации PDF документа в набор Image'ей. Далее печатаю с помощью PrintDocument. 
Код печати выгляди так:

```
private static void ImagesPrinting(string printerName, List<Image> images)
    {

        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;

        bool end = false;
        printDoc.EndPrint += (s, e) =>
        {
            end = true;
        };

        int curPage = 0;
        printDoc.PrintPage += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(images[curPage++], e.PageBounds);

            if (curPage >= images.Count)
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            else
                e.HasMorePages = true;
        };


        printDoc.Print();

        while (!end)
            Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что принтер печатает изображения повернутыми на 90 градусов. Установка Landscape в True, поворачивает изображение на 180 градусов от желаемого. 
Интересно то, что печать самого PDF документа средствами AcrobatReader проходит нормально и печатается как надо, без переопределения настроек. Грешил на растерайзер, но нет. Картинки получаются нормальные(сохранял, смотрел). Если печатать картинки из средства просмотра Windows, то же все нормально.

Есть идеи?

Comment: Подключите PrintPreviewDialog и посмотрите как выглядит страница до печати. Также стоит обратить внимание на настройки печати и дефолтные настройки принтера. Может банально указан другой формат бумаги (А3 или А5 вместо А4 например).

Comment: @rdorn Ну так я ведь настройки печати не меняю. Явно во всяком случае. И дефолтные настройки принтера не трогаю. Что такого может делать(или не делать) мой код, что печать происходит криво, тогда как AcrobatReader и стандартное средство просмотра изображений печатают корректно.

Comment: Ваш код нормальный, как минимум ничего лишнего. А вот нужного может не хватать, поэтому и написал проверить как выглядит страница до печати в предпросмотре и настройки принтера.